# Getting the locked-in app in iPad to access other apps?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm looking for some method to lock down an iPad to only limited usage. I have a dashboard for several games, and the said games themselves. They are the only apps I want the users to access. I also wish to lock down the native settings, and have a special app that provide limited options of settings to the user.

I understand that there's a guided access option, but it doesn't seem sufficient for what I'm trying to accomplish. Is what I'm desiring to do possible without jailbreaking? If so, how?

Comment: Try apple.stackexchange.com as STACKOVERFLOW.COM is related to programming.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MDM to decide what applications can be used on the device.
https://www.apple.com/iphone/business/it/management.html

An interesting discussion about the differences between Apple's MDM and Configurator (Apple App):
http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/Apple_Configurator_vs_MDM